# Android Recyclerview alternative for widget

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-widget

I have a use case were a user can create own buttons and give each button a label.

To display the buttons correctly i use Recyclerview with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. This works like a charm.

Unfortunately Recyclerview  is not supported on Android Widget.

What do you think is the best solution to display an arbitrary amount of buttons (each button can be of different sizes) on a widget? Should I use a GridLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) all the layouts that are supported to use in android widgets.

Of all the supported layouts listed the one that is closer in appearance to StaggeredGridLayout is the GridLayout. So, I would pick GridLayout to start with and then depending on my design needs I would combine it with what fits my needs best. Most probably, if you want to keep StaggeredGridLayout's default appearance, maybe you can combine it with some LinearLayouts wherever needed.